# Upstart script is not run (there is no syntactical error)

Tags: upstart

I created a job in `/etc/init` directory with `sudo vi myjob.conf`. In this file I wrote:

```
description "testing"
author "harshil"

start on mysig
exec echo testjob ran at [`date`]
console output
```

It is supposed to be started on and execute the command and print

```
test job ran at [`date`]
```

in terminal, when we execute the command `initctl emit mysig` on command line but it shows nothing.

What's wrong with it? What is prerequisite to make a file in `/etc/init` and run as upstart?

(**NOTE**:I already checked for syntactical errors in `myjob.conf` file using the command `init-checkconf myjob.conf`, and there are no errors)

Comment: Press Ctrl-Alt-F1, that's where `console` output goes, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo` command writes to STDOUT. At the time your job runs, STDOUT is not pointed to anywhere useful.

```
echo "testjob ran at [`date`]" >>/tmp/myjob.log
```

will save the output.

Comment: I want to start the job( `myjob.conf`) manually through CLI by using `initctl emit mysig` and also I gave output to console using `console output` at the end of the script...

Comment: Look at what your file descriptors (0,1,2) point to with `/bin/ls -l /proc/$$/fd >/tmp/fd` in your script